# Cannot control the fan on a Sony Vaio laptop

Tags: fan, vaio

I've got Sony Vaio laptop and my fan is on all the time, though the temperature on the video-adapter is always over 60°С.

As I've googled, [vaiofand](http://vaio-utils.org/fan/) does not support VPC-EA series.

Is there anything I can do with that or I need another laptop?

I'm using the following graphics card: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]` though the problem is not with the graphics card.

I've mentioned its temperature as the highest (64°C now btw). Seems like the notebook is always overheated and I cannot control the fan speed to make it cooler. And yes, I'm using the proprietary driver `ATI/AMD FGLRX` graphics driver.

I'm using Kubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu - what version of ubuntu are you using (edit your reply into your question).  What is your graphics card (`lspci | grep VGA`) and are you using any additional graphics drivers in Additional Drivers - if so what is it?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the following graphics card:


`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]`

though the problem is not with the graphics card. I've mentioned its temperature as the highest (64°C now btw). Seems like the notebook is always overheated and I cannot control the fan speed to make it cooler.

And yes, I'm using the proprietary driver `ATI/AMD FGLRX graphics driver`

Comment: @Xobb - Thanks - please try to edit replies back into your question.  What version of Ubuntu are you using e.g. ubuntu 11.04, Kubuntu 10.04 etc?

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this design so I was a bit confused. But already got it. Updated the post. Is there anything else I may provide about the system?

Comment: I won't add this as an answer just yet - this guy here installed the very latest graphics drivers and it reduced the fan speed noise - maybe worth a try? http://ccgi.philfam.co.uk/wordpress/2011/07/11/66

Comment: Ok, I'm trying that manual now. I will let you know about the results. Thanks!

Comment: @fossfreedom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1225/discussion-between-xobb-and-fossfreedom)

Comment: Hi, I am using the following graphic card on my VPCS11M9R 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev a2). I found that I don't have any possibility to control the fans even from nvidia-settings manager. Maybe you have some suggestions, how to let the fans be more quite in my particular case? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the very latest [AMD graphics drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx):

In the download drivers section, select "Notebook Graphics/Radeon HD Series/MobilityRadeon HD 5xxxSeries//Linux X86"

Download the file and run it:

```
sh ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run

aticonfig --initial -f
```

This should help the temperature of the graphics card and hopefully reduce the overall laptop fan noise.

[source](http://ccgi.philfam.co.uk/wordpress/2011/07/11/66)

Comment: Please note, this was absolutely valid for the 11.04, but when trying to make it work on 11.10 it fails. If you've tried that and afterwards you get your X server not running properly (black screen when the gdm/kdm should apper) go to rescue mode and launch sh /usr/share/ati/fglx_uninstall.sh to remove the driver.

Comment: The driver has been updated since, now it works fine.